# Comparing the MD5 results of split files against the MD5 of the whole

Tags: split, compare, md5, average, md5sum

I have a situation where I have one VERY large file that I'm using the linux "split" command to break into smaller parts.  Later I use the linux "cat" command to bring the parts all back together again.

In the interim, however, I'm curious...

If I get an MD5 fingerprint on the large file before splitting it, then later get the MD5 fingerprints on all the independent file parts that result from the split command, is there a way to take the independent fingerprints and somehow deduce that the sum or average (or whatever you like to all it) of their parts is equal to the fingerprint of the single large file?

By (very) loose example...

```
bigoldfile.txt MD5 = 737da789
smallfile1.txt MD5 = 23489a89
smallfile2.txt MD5 = 1238g89d
smallfile3.txt MD5 = 01234cd7
```

someoperator(23489a89,1238g89d,01234cd7) = 737da789 (the fingerprint of the original file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely can't do that - MD5 is complex enough inside and depends on actual data as well as the "initial" hash value.

You could instead generate "incremental" hashes - hash of first part, hash of first plus second part, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  What I'm attempting to do is verify the integrity of the parts against the original file (without bringing all the parts back together again and doing an MD5 on the resulting, merged file).  Perhaps MD5 isn't the best way to go?

Comment: @Joe: What exactly is the problem? You don't want to create a merged file, do you?

Comment: Yes, I still need all the parts.  Yes, I will eventually create a merged file from the parts using something like "cat smallfile* >bigoldfile.txt".  The file is being broken into parts to allow tranferring them to DVDs.  Prior to burnng the discs, I want to verify the integrity of the parts against the whole.

Comment: @Joe: I see. Yes, that's a problem. One solution is to write a program that will just read those files one by one and feed data into MD5 calculator - then you won't need to recreate the file. Doing this in C, C++ or C# isn't hard.

Comment: @sharptooth... Thanks.  I was hoping for a solution that could use native linux commands, but I guess that was just wishful thinking.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Joe: Maybe there is such solution, you just have to ask a separate question about it. I can't help you here - my experience with Linux is rather limited.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly but the next best thing would be to do this:
cat filepart1 filepart2 | md5sum
  or 
cat filepart* | md5sum

Be sure to cat them back together in the correct order. 
by piping the output of cat you don't have to worry about creating a combined file that is too large.